# Select openrowset from excel file in dynamic dateformat in filename

Tags: sql, sql-server

I cannot do select my excel file in openrowset in sql server. Here's my query but the result still null:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.OLEDB.12.0',
'Excel 12.0;Database=\\DB\A\B\FILE1_(select CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))_1.xlsx',
'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')
```

I also tried using parameter like this:

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME
SET @date = GETDATE()

SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.OLEDB.12.0',
'Excel 12.0;Database=\\DB\A\B\FILE1_'+@date'_1.xlsx',
'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')
```

Expected for the filename result is current date format like this:

```
FILE1_20211111_1.xlsx
```

Comment: Functions inside a literal string aren't derived. The literal string `'GETDATE()'` doesn't return the current date and time in a string; it returns the literal string `'GETDATE()'`. You'll need to use dynamic SQL here.

Comment: @larnu can you give me example for that? thanks